# Addition of two 3x3 matrices in TCL scripting

Tags: matrix, tcl, addition

I'm started with TCL scripting recently. I'm finding difficulty in writing a script that adds two 3x3 matrices and prints the result.
Here is what I have tried:

```
set arr1 {{1 2 3} {4 5 6} {7 8 9}}
set arr2 {{3 2 1} {6 4 5} {8 9 7}}
foreach a $arr1 b $arr2 {
    foreach c $a d $b {
        set sum [expr $c + $d]
        lappend z $sum
    }
    lappend y $z
    unset z
}  
puts $y
```

The above script gives me `{4 4 4} {10 9 11} {15 17 16}`

Is there any better way to get the same result ?

Comment: If you are embarking on a more extensive set of matrix operations, consider the tcllib math::linearalgebra package. As this is Tcl, the source is readily available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do approximately that much work. However, there are some optimisations possible, of which the only truly important one is *brace your expressions* (to enable compiling them). Here's that addition as a one-liner:

```
set y [lmap a $arr1 b $arr2 {lmap c $a d $b {expr {$c+$d}}}]
```

Splitting things up, renaming variables, and adding some whitespace:

```
set y [lmap row1 $arr1 row2 $arr2 {
    lmap cell1 $row1 cell2 $row2 {
        expr {$cell1 + $cell2}
    }
}]
```

`lmap` is like `foreach` except it makes a list out of the values it gets for evaluating its body (`foreach` throws that away). Using an `lmap` inside an `lmap` makes the addition work over the cells. (You'll get the most optimised compilation of this code if you put it in a procedure.)

---

Getting better than this requires using a package such as [VecTcl](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/VecTcl) that can hoist the computation into C.